# Generics double interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, wildcard

```
public interface IFoo
public class Foo : IFoo
public interface ILang<T> where T:IFoo
public class Lang : ILang<Foo>
```

But now, I want something like this with wildcard

```
public class CarroMontadora<T> where T:ILang<?>
```

Beacause this does not work with my interface:

```
public class MYCLASS<T> where T:ILang<IFoo>
```

And this is not too smart to do, because is not so generics:

```
public class MYCLASS<T,U> where T:ILang<U> where U: IFoo
```

Comment: Is this a Java question or a c# question?

Comment: The syntax is C# (`:` vs `implements`); why is it also tagged with "java"?

Comment: You can inherit from multiple interfaces in C# without involving generic type constraints.

Comment: Can you use real world class names? I find type system questions easier if I can picture a concrete scenario. I'm not good at abstract type algebra.

Comment: Sorry about tagged Java, it was my first question, and I know that I can user wildcards in java, like this example: public class MYCLASS<T> where T extends ILang<?>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to add another generic parameter to your new class:

```
public class CarroMontadora<T1, T2>
    where T2 : IFoo
    where T1 : ILang<T2>
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Good options already listed but let me give you another one.

Have both `ILang<T>` AND a simple marker interface `ILang` - use `ILang` to enforce that condition and make `ILang<T> : ILang`

It's not flawlessly type-safe but that API is pretty clear enough that it is unlikely that someone will screw it up.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested constraints on generics on C# without having both type parameters as part of the class (your third example), however you can enforce this in a cleaner fashion by good old method signatures.

For example

```
public class CarroMontadora<T> where T: IFoo {

    public CarroMontadora(ILang<T> param) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```